# ADB needs reset always

Tags: android

Whenever I run my emulator for the first time, it shows up but doesnt start my app and I find no device in DDMS view UNTIL I reset the ADB. It happens always FOR THE FIRST TIME. But after I reset the ADB it works from then on.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall Android on your system.

Comment: I agree, also make sure all your "Android SDK" files and etc are all gone from where you initially installed it -- not just a reinstall of eclipse or anything!

Comment: Try to see if doing just that works, if not that you will have to do the complete uninstall and reinstall.