# Android emulator disconnects on incoming call

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to debug an app that has PhoneStateListener, I'm testing it on API 18 ARM emulator. My debugger is connected fine until the point I try to simulate an incoming call through Eclipse DDMS (Telephony actions -> Voice call). Then my debugger disconnects and I'm not able to step through my code again.

Is this by design or an error?

Comment: it shouldn't have happened. I am too developing an app which uses simulator to make calls but am not facing any disconnection. Are you using BlueStack? it's service running in background sometimes causes disconnection. If so, then stop the service from `task manager` (assuming u are using windows).
do you know how to reconnect the `adb` without restarting `emulator`. if not see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880119/adb-needs-reset-always

Comment: I'm running standard Android emulator. I can reconnect with resetting adb server fine, but I have not ever been able to step in with debugger in a PhoneStateListener :(

Comment: That might be a software problem. From last 2 months i have been working on an app that requires calling from DDMS and i place atleast 100 calls a day using DDMS and have never faced any problem.  Try upgrading eclipse and DDMS and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Windows. This issue doesn't happen on OSX. Were you able to find any solution?

Comment: not really, I gave up on that application

Answer (score 2):

I am also faced this issue,

During call time adb gets disconnected

I have tried adb server start and stop using below commands

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`

* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *

* daemon started successfully *

`adb devices`

List of devices attached

emulator-5554   device